# Números aleatórios se repetindo

Tags: java, android

Bom galera, é o seguinte: Eu tenho um método que gera números aleatórios, e na activity eu trato para não repetir esses números, porém ocorre que eles se repetem. O que eu estou fazendo errado?

Método:

```
private int numeroAleatorio() {
    int numero = 0;
    //set aumenta a quantidade dos números gerados
    if (set == 1) {
        List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            numeros.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(numeros);
        numero = (Integer) numeros.get(0);
    }
    if (set == 2) {
        List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
            numeros.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(numeros);
        numero = (Integer) numeros.get(0);
    }
    if (set == 3) {
        List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
            numeros.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(numeros);
        numero = (Integer) numeros.get(0);
    }
    return numero;
}
```

Activity (para não repetir o número):

```
 esc = numeroDecisao();
 res1 = numeroAleatorio();
 res2 = numeroAleatorio();

 resposta = res1 + res2;

 if (esc == 1) {
 val1 = resposta;
 val2 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
 val3 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
 val4 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();

 do {
       if ((val2 == val1) || (val2 == val3) || (val2 == val4)) {
            val2 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();

      } else {
            passou = 1;
      }
  } while (passou != 1);

do {
     if ((val3 == val1) || (val3 == val2) || (val3 == val4)) {
       val3 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
     } else {
    passou = 1;
     }
  } while (passou != 1);

 do {
      if ((val4 == val1) || (val4 == val2) || (val4 == val3)) {

        val4 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
      } else {
        passou = 1;
       }
   } while (passou != 1);

                    } else if (esc == 2) {
                        val1 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio());
                        val2 = resposta;
                        val3 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio());
                        val4 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio());

                        do {
                            if ((val1 == val2) || (val1 == val3) || (val1 == val4)) {

                                val1 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
                            } else {
                                passou = 1;
                            }
                        } while (passou != 1);

                        do {
                            if ((val3 == val2) || (val3 == val1) || (val3 == val4)) {

                                val3 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
                            } else {
                                passou = 1;
                            }
                        } while (passou != 1);

                        do {
                            if ((val4 == val2) || (val4 == val1) || (val4 == val3)) {
                                val4 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();

                            } else {
                                passou = 1;
                            }
                        } while (passou != 1);

                    } else if (esc == 3) {
                        val1 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio());
                        val2 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio());
                        val3 = resposta;
                        val4 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio());

                        do {
                            if ((val1 == val3) || (val1 == val2) || (val1 == val4)) {
                                val1 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();

                            } else {
                                passou = 1;
                            }
                        } while (passou != 1);

                        do {
                            if ((val2 == val3) || (val2 == val1) || (val2 == val4)) {
                                val2 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();

                            } else {
                                passou = 1;
                            }
                        } while (passou != 1);

                        do {
                            if ((val4 == val3) || (val4 == val1) || (val4 == val2)) {

                                val4 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
                            } else {
                                passou = 1;
                            }
                        } while (passou != 1);

                    } else if (esc == 4) {
                        val1 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio());
                        val2 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio());
                        val3 = (numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio());
                        val4 = resposta;

                        do {
                            if ((val1 == val4) || (val1 == val2) || (val1 == val3)) {
                                val1 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
                            } else {

                                passou = 1;
                            }
                        } while (passou != 1);

                        do {
                            if ((val2 == val4) || (val2 == val1) || (val2 == val3)) {

                                val2 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
                            } else {
                                passou = 1;
                            }
                        } while (passou != 1);

                        do {
                            if ((val3 == val4) || (val3 == val1) || (val3 == val2)) {

                                val3 = numeroAleatorio() + numeroAleatorio();
                            } else {
                                passou = 1;
                            }
                        } while (passou != 1);
                    }

                    num1.setText(Integer.toString(res1));
                    num2.setText(Integer.toString(res2));
                    op1.setText(Integer.toString(val1));
                    op2.setText(Integer.toString(val2));
                    op3.setText(Integer.toString(val3));
                    op4.setText(Integer.toString(val4));
```

Comment: [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132)?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Provavelmente. Este código é absurdamente mais complexo do que deveria, o que facilita cometer erros.

Comment: Compreendo, mas teria uma solução?

Comment: Christian, o que você está tentando fazer? O que você queria ou não queria que aparecesse no `num1`, `num2`, `op1`, `op2`, `op3` e `op4`?

Comment: Da forma como constrói as sequências elas não têm números repetidos. No entanto, chamadas diferentes ao método `numeroAleatorio()` podem ter como resultado números iguais.

Comment: num1 e num2 são números aleatórios a parte, no op1, op2, op3, op4 são resultados de contas de adição, que são calculados através dos do - while. No começo há o if (esc == 1) que um if que gera números aleatórios de 1 a 4, e para cada caso a resposta entre a soma do num1 + num2, é setado em um botão (op1, op2, op3, op4). Por exemplo se o esc == 1 a resposta do num1+num2, estará no op1 e os demais estão com respostas erradas. As vezes ocorrem que essas respostas fiquem iguais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer isso:

```
private int numeroAleatorio() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * set * 10 + 1);
}
```

```
int esc = numeroDecisao();
int res1 = numerosAleatorio();
int res2 = numerosAleatorio();
int soma = res1 + res2;

Set<Integer> respostas = new HashSet<>();
respostas.add(soma);

while (respostas.size() < 4) {
    int a = numeroAleatorio();
    int b = numeroAleatorio();
    respostas.add(a + b);
}

respostas.remove(soma);

Iterator<Integer> it = respostas.iterator();

num1.setText(Integer.toString(res1));
num2.setText(Integer.toString(res2));
op1.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 1 ? soma : it.next()));
op2.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 2 ? soma : it.next()));
op3.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 3 ? soma : it.next()));
op4.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 4 ? soma : it.next()));
```

Os seus erros eram que:

- Observe que se o `set` é 1, você quer gerar números de 1 até 10, se for 2, quer de 1 a 20 e se for 3, de 1 a 30. Logo, você quer gerar números de 1 até `set * 10`. Sempre prefira usar matemática do que um monte de `if`s com código copiado e colado.
- Para escolher **um** número aleatório, você gerava um monte de números (de acordo com o `10 * set`) e os embaralhava para pegar apenas o primeiro. Há uma fórmula matemática que dá esse resultado de uma forma mais simples:

  1. Comece com um número real aleatório `x` tal que `0 <= x < 1` ([`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) produz isso).
  2. Multiplique `x` pela quantidade de números existentes no intervalo desejado. Como os números são de 1 até `set * 10`, então a quantidade de números no intervalo desejado é `set * 10`. Isso vai produzir um número real tal que `0 <= x < set * 10`, ou seja, um número de 0 até `set * 10 - 1`.
  3. Some o limite mínimo do intervalo, que no seu caso é 1. Isso vai gerar um número real no intervalo de 1 até `set * 10`.
  4. Faça um *cast* para `int`, assim o resultado será um inteiro de 1 até `set * 10`.

  E tudo isso acima pode ser expresso em uma só linha:

  ```
  return (int) (Math.random() * set * 10 + 1);
  ```
- Todos os casos separados pelo `esc` são parecidos, então convém-se evitar separá-los. Lembre-se o `if` serve para separar casos distintos, e não casos semelhantes com pequenas diferenças.
- O [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) é um conjunto que não permite repetições. Assim sendo é mais fácil acrescentar-se neles os números até que você tenha 4 números distintos.
- O [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) permite retirar-se elementos de uma coleção um por um por meio do método [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--).
- O operador ternário `? :` é seu amigo. Saiba usá-lo (mas não abuse dele).

Comment: Victor, valeu ainda não tive a oportunidade de testar, mas assim que possível darei o meu feedback

Comment: Victor, tive a oportunidade de testar e funcionou para uma situação, valeu mesmo. Porém para uma situação diferente não resolveu o problema de repetição. A situação é a seguinte: tenho uma conta na tela tipo assim: x + 1 = 2, o usuário tem que clicar na opção que completa a conta e eu tentei usar este código que você passou, porém não funcionou, como eu poderia altera-lo para a situação que descrevi anteriormente?

Comment: @ChristianGomesdaSilva Neste caso recomendo criar uma pergunta nova. O seu código já deve estar bem diferente e isso daí que você está colocando agora já é um problema também razoavelmente diferente. Coloque na pergunta nova, um link para essa daqui.

Comment: Victor, como eu faço para colocar o link na pergunta?

Comment: @ChristianGomesdaSilva `[minha pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254984/80918)` - sem espaços no meio.

Comment: Fiz a nova pergunta