# Repetição de Números

Tags: java, android

Bom pessoal eu tenho a seguinte situação: tenho uma conta na tela tipo assim: `x + 1 = 2`, o usuário tem que clicar na opção que completa a conta e eu tentei usar este código [da minha pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254984/80918), porém não funcionou. No caso, tenho que deixar um valor de `x` "fixo", e acaba repetindo este número.

Segue o código que tenho:

```
            esc = numeroDecisao();
            res1 = numeroAleatorio();
            res2 = numeroAleatorio();
            resultadoConta = res1 + res2;

            Set<Integer> respostas = new HashSet<>();
            respostas.add(resultadoConta);

            while (respostas.size() < 4) {
                int a = numeroAleatorio();
                int b = numeroAleatorio();
                respostas.add(a + b);
            }
            respostas.remove(resultadoConta);
            Iterator<Integer> iterator = respostas.iterator();

            if (esc == 1) {
                op1.setText(Integer.toString(res1));
                op2.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 2 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));
                op3.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 3 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));
                op4.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 4 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));

            } else if (esc == 2) {
                op1.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 1 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));
                op2.setText(Integer.toString(res1));
                op3.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 3 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));
                op4.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 4 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));

            } else if (esc == 3) {
                op1.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 1 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));
                op2.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 2 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));
                op3.setText(Integer.toString(res1));
                op4.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 4 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));

            } else if (esc == 4) {
                op1.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 1 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));
                op2.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 2 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));
                op3.setText(Integer.toString(esc == 3 ? resultadoConta : iterator.next()));
                op4.setText(Integer.toString(res1));
            }
            num2.setText(Integer.toString(res2));
            txt_resultado.setText(Integer.toString(resultadoConta));
```

No caso, o `res1` seria o `x` da conta `x + 1 = 2`.

Comment: Coloque o seu código atual aqui ao invés de apenas apontar para a pergunta anterior como se nada tivesse mudado. O link era para ser apenas um detalhe para explicar melhor o contexto para quem fosse responder a pergunta, não era para o link ser praticamente a pergunta inteira.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, obrigado pela a dica, estou aprendendo ainda a como realizar as perguntas devidas no stack. Realizei a edição e coloquei o trecho do código.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, você não precisa desses `if (esc == 1)`, `if (esc == 2)`, etc. O código da resposta da pergunta anterior foi feito para que você tivesse o mesmo código não importando qual é o `esc`. Vou repetir o que coloquei [na minha resposta da pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254993/132):

> **Sempre prefira usar matemática do que um monte de `if`s com código copiado e colado.**

[image: Não vou escrever um monte de ifs com código copiado e colado.]

Segundo, vamos simplificar um pouco a geração de números aleatórios:

```
private static final Random RND = new Random();

private int numeroAleatorio() {
    return RND.nextInt(set * 10) + 1;
}
```

Terceiro, que você tem `resultadoConta = res1 + res2` porque você estava fazendo uma conta do tipo `X = A + B`, onde `A` e `B` eram os números dados e `X` era o valor desconhecido a ser respondido. Agora você tem contas no formato `X + A = B`, e provavelmente vai ter outras tais como `X - A = B`, `A + X = B`, `A - X = B`, `A * B = X`, `X * A = B`, `A / X = B`, `AX = B`, etc.

Para modelar todas essas contas possíveis, primeiro use uma classe para representar a operação:

```
public class Conta {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int x;
    private String formato;

    public Conta(int a, int b, int x, String formato) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.x = x;
        this.formato = formato
                .replace("A", String.valueOf(a))
                .replace("B", String.valueOf(b));
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public String getFormato() {
        return formato;
    }

    public String getTermo1() {
        return formato.split(" ")[0];
    }

    public String getOperacao() {
        return formato.split(" ")[1];
    }

    public String getTermo2() {
        return formato.split(" ")[2];
    }

    public String getResultado() {
        return formato.split(" ")[4];
    }
}
```

E então use uma interface para representar todos os tipos de operações possíveis e gerar os números de acordo:

```
public interface ModeloConta {
    public Conta fazerConta();
}
```

E com essa interface, gere um monte de implementações em um array:

```
ModeloConta[] modelos = {
    new ModeloConta() {
        @Override
        public Conta fazerConta() {
            int a = numeroAleatorio();
            int b = numeroAleatorio();
            int x = a + b;
            return new Conta(a, b, x, "A + B = X");
        }
    },

    new ModeloConta() {
        @Override
        public Conta fazerConta() {
            int a = numeroAleatorio();
            int x = numeroAleatorio();
            int b = a + x;
            return new Conta(a, b, x, "A + X = B");
        }
    },

    new ModeloConta() {
        @Override
        public Conta fazerConta() {
            int a = numeroAleatorio();
            int x = numeroAleatorio();
            int b = a + x;
            return new Conta(a, b, x, "X + A = B");
        }
    },

    new ModeloConta() {
        @Override
        public Conta fazerConta() {
            int a = numeroAleatorio();
            int x = numeroAleatorio();
            int b = a * x;
            return new Conta(a, b, x, "A * X = B");
        }
    },

    new ModeloConta() {
        @Override
        public Conta fazerConta() {
            int x = numeroAleatorio();
            int a = numeroAleatorio();
            int b = x - a;
            return new Conta(a, b, x, "X - A = B");
        }
    }
};
```

Se você estiver usando Java 8 ou superior, esse código acima pode ser simplificado para isso:

```
ModeloConta[] modelos = {
    () -> {
        int a = numeroAleatorio();
        int b = numeroAleatorio();
        int x = a + b;
        return new Conta(a, b, x, "A + B = X");
    },

    () -> {
        int a = numeroAleatorio();
        int x = numeroAleatorio();
        int b = a + x;
        return new Conta(a, b, x, "A + X = B");
    },

    () -> {
        int a = numeroAleatorio();
        int x = numeroAleatorio();
        int b = a + x;
        return new Conta(a, b, x, "X + A = B");
    },

    () -> {
        int a = numeroAleatorio();
        int x = numeroAleatorio();
        int b = a * x;
        return new Conta(a, b, x, "A * X = B");
    },

    () -> {
        int x = numeroAleatorio();
        int a = numeroAleatorio();
        int b = x - a;
        return new Conta(a, b, x, "X - A = B");
    }
};
```

Coloque no array todos os modelos de contas que você tiver. Tendo então os modelos, você adapta o código anterior para escolher um modelo e usar. Também vou usar um array de `TextView` caso você queira mais do que quatro respostas e também para ter certeza que você não vai querer substituir isso por um monte de `if`s horrorosos:

```
TextView[] opcoes = {op1, op2, op3, op4 /*, op5, op6, op7, quantas você quiser */};
ModeloConta modeloEscolhido = modelos[RND.nextInt(modelos.length)];
Conta conta = modeloEscolhido.fazerConta();
int respostaCerta = conta.getX();
esc = RND.nextInt(opcoes.length);

Set<Integer> respostas = new HashSet<>();
respostas.add(respostaCerta);

while (respostas.size() < opcoes.length) {
    respostas.add(modeloEscolhido.fazerConta().getX());
}
respostas.remove(conta.getX());
Iterator<Integer> respostasErradas = respostas.iterator();

for (int i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++) {
    int valor = esc == i ? respostaCerta : respostasErradas.next();
    opcoes[i].setText(Integer.toString(valor));
}

num1.setText(conta.termo1());
sinal.setText(conta.operacao());
num2.setText(conta.termo2());
txt_resultado.setText(conta.resultado());
```

As variáveis `res1`, `res2` e `resultadoConta` devem então ser deletadas. O método `numeroDecisao()` também deve ser deletado. Acrescentei uma `TextView` chamada `sinal` para guardar o sinal desejado para a operação.

Aliás, se preferir, você pode substituir `num1`, `sinal`, `num2` e `txt_resultado` por uma única `TextView` que vai ter a conta inteira. Nesse caso, você trocaria isso:

```
num1.setText(conta.getTermo1());
sinal.setText(conta.getOperacao());
num2.setText(conta.getTermo2());
txt_resultado.setText(conta.getResultado());
```

Por isso:

```
txtConta.setText(conta.getFormato());
```

Onde `txtConta` seria a `TextView` na qual você mostraria a conta (vai aparecer como also semelhante a `5 + X = 12`). Tendo essa nova `TextView`, você deletaria as `TextView`s `num1`, `num2`, `sinal` e `txt_resultado`. Também poderia deletar os métodos `getTermo1()`, `getOperaco()`, `getTermo2()` e `getResultado()` da classe `Conta`.